# AuthorizationQueryParametersError while creating the presigned url for my private bucket object, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

as i try to create a presigned url for my png file in my private s3 bucket while, doing so i got this error, how to resolve it

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
<Message>Query-string authentication version 4 requires the X-Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential, X-Amz-Signature, X-Amz-Date, X-Amz-SignedHeaders, and X-Amz-Expires parameters.</Message>
```

my code

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'
 
#credentials below for the IAM user I am using

s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(

 region: 'us-east-1', 

access_key_id: Access_Key_Id,

secret_access_key: Secret_access_key
 
)
 
signer = Aws::S3::Presigner.new(client: s3)

url = signer.presigned_url(

 :put_object,

 bucket: 'my bucketname',

 key: "${engine.png}-#{SecureRandom.uuid}"

)
```

Comment: I did some basic editing to add code blocks but you should clean up this code so that its readable.